# $|Q(f)-Q_N(f)|\le CN^{-s}\Big(\int_{0}^{2\pi}|f(t)|^2+|f^{(s)}(t)|^2\Big)^{1/2}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, inequality, numerical-methods

Let $f \in C^s(\mathbb R)$ be $2\pi$-periodic, $n \in \mathbb N, N:=2n+1$ and let $q_N$ be the trigonometric interpolation polynomial of $f$:

$$q_N(t)=\frac{a_0}{2}+\sum_{k=1}^{n}(a_k\cos kt + b_k\sin kt)$$

nodes: $t_j:=\frac{2\pi j}{N}, \ \ \ j=0,\ldots,N-1$.

Let $Q(f):=\int_{0}^{2\pi}f(x)dx$ be the exact integral and $Q_N(f):=Q(q_N)$ a quadrature rule.

How can I show that there is a constant $C>0$ such that

$$|Q(f)-Q_N(f)|\le CN^{-s}\Big(\int_{0}^{2\pi}|f(t)|^2+|f^{(s)}(t)|^2\Big)^{1/2}$$

Perhaps the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality is helpful:

For $f,g \in L^2([a,b])$:

$$|\int_{a}^{b}f(t)g(t)dt|^2\le \int_{a}^{b}|f(t)|^2dt\int_{a}^{b}|g(t)|^2dt$$